# Android Studio - I have troubles implementing one librery for Android Car

Tags: android, android-auto

Im trying to implement the library `'androidx.car.widget:widget:1.1.0'`

I already have the MavenCentral added on my repositories. but always when I try to build my project the library is not found (I already tried with 1.0.0v'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't one of the Jetpack libraries that Google publishes. https://maven.google.com/web/index.html?q=androidx.car.app#androidx.car.app is the list of the published Car App Library Jetpack artifacts.